# Update carrinho codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

Estou com um problema para atualizar a quantidade em um carrinho de compras utilizando o codeigniter, pois sempre que vou atualizar e o carrinho tiver por exemplo 3 itens, o carrinho só atualiza o último item e não atualiza os 2 primeiros.

Código da view

```
<?php echo form_open('shop/update_car'); ?>


    <?php foreach ($this->cart->contents() as $item): ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $item['name']; ?></td>
            <td>
                <?php if ($this->cart->has_options($item['rowid'])) {
                    foreach ($this->cart->product_options($item['rowid']) as $option => $value) {
                        echo $option . ": <em>" . $value . "</em>";
                    }

                } ?>
            </td>

            <td><?php echo form_input(array('name' => 'qtde[]', 'value' => $item['qty'], 'size' => '2')); ?></td>
             <?php echo form_hidden('rowid[]', $item['rowid']); ?>
            <td>R$ <?php echo number_format($item['price'],2,',','.'); ?></td>
            <td>R$ <?php echo number_format($item['subtotal'],2,',','.'); ?></td>
            <td class="remove">
                <?php echo anchor('shop/remove/'.$item['rowid'],'X'); ?>
            </td>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    <tr class="total">
        <td colspan="3"></td>
        <td><?php echo form_submit('', 'atualizar carrinho');?></td>

        <td><strong>Total</strong> R$ <?php echo number_format($this->cart->total(),2,',','.'); ?></td>
    </tr>
    </table>        
</div>
```

codigo controller shop

```
function update_car(){

    $value    = $this->input->post('rowid');
    $quantity = $this->input->post('qtde');

    foreach($value as $values){

        foreach($quantity as $quantitys){

            $update = array(

            'rowid' => $values,
            'qty' => $quantitys 

            );      

        }

    }



    $this->cart->update($update);

    redirect('shop');       
}
```

Comment: o `update()` só é aplicado no último, pq ele está fora do foreach e também pelo fato de `$update` ser reatribuida a cada volta do foreach.

Comment: oi, ja coloquei dentro do foreach mais interno, e msm assim nao funcionou, agora ta se eu atualizar o ultimo ele esta atualizando tudo!!

Comment: Um for normal parece melhor nessa situação pq imagino que `rowid` e `qtde` sejam array com o mesmo número de elementos, ai é so acertar o indice e mandar pro banco, isso mata o foreach mais interno.

Comment: vc pode me passar como eu posso implementar isso, por favor

Comment: mais alguem pode me ajudar!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problema:**

Como o `update()` está fora do foreach apenas o último item será atualizado veja que a atribuição à `$update` é refeita a cada volta do segundo foreach.

**Solução**

Parece que `$value` e `$quantity` tem o mesmo número de elementos e estão relacionados, nesse caso é melhor trocar os foreachs por um for normal.

```
function update_car(){
    $value    = $this->input->post('rowid');
    $quantity = $this->input->post('qtde');

    $total = count($quantity);

    for($i=0; $i<$total; $i++){
        $update = array('rowid' => $value[$i], 'qtde' => $quantity[$i]);
        $this->cart->update($update);
    }
    redirect('shop');  
}
```

Comment: Obrigado rray funcionou perfeitamente!! :-)